# Using Modal on Angular 2 (Ng2Bs3Modal)

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some problems trying to input a modal on my Angular 2 application.

I'm using the `Ng-2Bs3-Modal` plugin, so far I've done everything it says on their [walkthrough](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal) but when I click on the button that should activate the modal nothing happens.

Here's how the code looks like:

On `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
@NgModule({
  imports: [Ng2Bs3ModalModule],
})
```

There's the `index.html` where I linked the `jquery`, `bootstrap` and the modal itself:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/bundles/ng2-bs3-modal.js"></script>
```

Here's the html from the component:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.open()">Open me!</button>
<modal #modal>
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        Hello World!
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

and the `ts` file from this html:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {FiltroDisputaService} from '../services/filtro-disputa.service'
import {DisputaService} from '../../disputas/disputas/services/disputas.service'
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'filtro-disputa',
  templateUrl: `filtro-disputa.component.html`,
  providers: [FiltroDisputaService]
})

export class FiltroDisputaComponent {
  campanhas:FiltroDisputaComponent[] = []
  disputas:any;
  loading = false;
  @ViewChild('modal')
  modal: ModalComponent;
  constructor(private service: FiltroDisputaService, private disputa_service: DisputaService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.service
      .lista()
      .subscribe(campanhas => {
        this.campanhas = campanhas;
        console.log("campanhas", this.campanhas)
        this.loading = false;
      }, erro => {
        console.log("erro")
        this.loading = false;
      })
  }

  open(){
    console.log("test");
    this.modal.open();
  }
}
```

There's also this code from the `systemjs.config.js`:

```
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        'ng2-bs3-modal': 'node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal'
    },
```

I'm not getting any error, the only problem is that the modal just do not open.

I'm open to suggestions of other plugins but I've already tried a few and always got some problem.

Comment: If you already imported it in index.html thru <script>, why you did this again thru SystemJS?

Comment: I just put in the question, but this code was actually commented

Comment: Code looks same as the tutorial. Weird, if you did not get any JS error, it there any other error? Like network? Or maybe try recompiling the code?

Comment: I'm not getting any error :(, it's really weird

Comment: do you know any other plugin that is easy to use or that you've already used?

Comment: Why not using MD?https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog